# get Scope ID in entity framework 6 after saving data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I have implemented repository pattern and unit of work on top of Data Access Layer. I have all the crud operation in Generic Repository but save method in unit of work. In my business class I am passing object to generic class, followed by Save method in unit of work, my question is how can i get scope ID from this point forward

Basically I need to get ID of object after saving where I don't know what is object ID name as I am using generic class to save data

```
 public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
 protected DbSet<TEntity> _DbSet;
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

    public GenericRepository()
    { }

    public GenericRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        this._dbContext = dbContext;
        _DbSet = _dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public void InsertEntity(TEntity obj)
    {
        _DbSet.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

...

```
 public class FunctionsNavigation_UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private FunctionContext _FunctionContext = new FunctionContext();

    uow.Qualification_FeeSchemeRepository.InsertEntity(obj);
 }
}

  public void Save()
    {
        _FunctionContext.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);

        _FunctionContext.SaveChanges();

    }
```

in following business class after saving I try to get ID on object but I am not getting any thing

```
  _uof.Sys_Nav_Functions_Repository.InsertEntity(_Sys_Nav_FunctionEntity);


   _uof.Save();

   _FunctionID = _obj.Sys_Nav_Function.Function_ID;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You will get the inserted `Id` at the object itself.

```
private FunctionContext _FunctionContext = new FunctionContext();

var obj = new yourEntity();
uow.Qualification_FeeSchemeRepository.InsertEntity(obj);
uow.Save();
```

Once you save the data into the database. The entity-framework will fill the entity type PK that is generated from the database.

In short you get here

```
int id = obj.Id;
```

**Update Inserting 1:1 Relationship Sample**

```
Person person = new Person//create person entity
{
   FirstName = "Eldho",
   LastName  = "Abe",
};

AuthorizedUser user = new AuthorizedUser//create authorized user role entity
{
   Person = person, //The reference of newly inserted user
   UserId = myUserid,
   HashedPassword = password,
};

uow.PersonDA.Insert(person);
uow.AuthorizedUserDA.Insert(user);

uow.Save();//insert to database
```

Comment: In some case where 1:1 relationship, I am using same key as primary and foreign key in dependency table, is there way to get true or false return to ensure data been saved

Comment: If your foreign key constrain is invalid , `SaveChanges()` will definitely thrown an exception and rollback the entire transaction . I will update a typical scenario in my answer

Comment: my pleasure @toxic happy coding